# abelian group of order p is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z/pZ}$?

Tags: group-theory, galois-theory

Is any abelian group of order $p$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z/pZ}$ for any prime $p$?

Comment: You can even drop the "abelian".  Every group of order $p$ is cyclic so abelian is automatic.  And, yes, cyclic implies the isomorphism you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A group of order $p$ is cyclic, so $\exists a \in G$ such that $G = \langle a \rangle$, i.e. $G = \{1,a,a^2,\ldots,a^{p-1}\}$. Now let $f: G \to \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$, $f(a^t) = \overline t$.

Comment: so it is an isomorphism?

Comment: @usere5225321 yes.